# Removing events in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some code in jquery which looks like this:

```
$("#filterZaal").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#filterGenre").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#filterZaal").live("change", interceptZaalFilter);
$("#filterDag").live("change", interceptDagFilter);
$("#filterGenre").live("change", interceptGenreFilter);
```

Now, i have added a button, and when i push this button i would like that all of the above code does not count anymore, so when i push the button, these events would no longer be called but when i push it again it should become enabled again.

How can i do this in jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than add/remove the events each time with `die()`, I'd just create a toggle flag:

```
var Toggle = false;

$("#filterZaal").live("change", function(){ 
  if(Toggle){ interceptZaalFilter(); }   // alterantively, add this check
  Toggle = !Toggle;                      // to the func you call
});
// and so on
```

This seems to better capture what you want, and will almost certainly be more efficient.

Comment: I was just going to leave the same answer. This will be much more efficient than constantly adding/removing handlers. +1

Answer (score 2):

have the event handlers check if `$('#theButton').hasClass('disabled')` and if so, they do `$('#theButton').removeClass('disabled')` and return false; else proceed normally

then when you add the button make sure it has a 'disabled' class

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/):

```
$("#filterZaal").die("change", interceptZaalFilter);
$("#filterDag").die("change", interceptDagFilter);
$("#filterGenre").die("change", interceptGenreFilter);
```